# how to know the use of my applications?

Tags: kernel, process, monitoring

I want to know how long my programs have been used. For example if I use my web browser i want to know the start and the close time to obtain a total of use time.

Basicly I want to know when an application starts an when its ends, and in function of the event do something like register the time in a file.

I've searched about listening kernel events or something like that but nothing. Also i tried with supervisord but it saids that the process close too quickly and not record anything.

Another of my attempts was to use the pyinotify library to monitor the /proc folders but that was a complete failure.

I'm working in Ubuntu. Any tips? Thanks in advance

These are my sources

https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify

http://supervisord.org/

Comment: A syslog monitoring tool might work for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the runtime of an application with a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

convertsecs() {
 ((h=${1}/3600))
 ((m=(${1}%3600)/60))
 ((s=${1}%60))
 printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n" $h $m $s
}

startime=$( date +%s )
firefox && endtime=$( date +%s ) 
let runtime=endtime-startime 
echo "$( date )""   You have run firefox for ""$( convertsecs $runtime )"  >> app-runtime.log
```

Source from the [convertsecs function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12199798)